# How to detect last record in mapper while fetching data from HBase Table

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, hadoop2

I am trying to read records from HBase table in my java mapper. I want to detect the last record to perform an operation on that. How can we identify the last record. I have a zero reducer. I cannot hold all the records in memory.

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case a bit more. What are you trying to accomplish. Do you want to find the last record in *every* mapper or last record *of all* mappers. (Of course, that is kind of wrong direction)

Comment: I am trying to read record by record and performing aggregations by grouping the records.

Comment: @BalakrishnaD, your answer does not really answer Shyam's question

Comment: I have only one mapper class and trying to detect the last record in HBase table I am reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine when a mapper has processed its final record when it calls its cleanup method:

```
cleanup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context)
```

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html

This will give you the ability to determine *per-mapper* when it has processed all of its key/values and take some action.

If you're trying to aggregate without using a reduce stage and you're reading from HBase i would assume you have some guarantees about the groupings of the data that would also help. For example you could look for a change of key entering a mapper and you would know you have received all keys that are the same.

Comment: I've overridden cleanup method and it worked. Thanks @Binary Nerd